# Common generic method to handle operations on subclasses of java.lang.Number

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I have a class `MyGen` which takes two generic arguments and has a method `getValue()`

```java
public interface MyGen<E,T> {

    T getValue();
}
```

Usually the second generic type would be either `Long` or `Integer`.

Then, I wrote a method to combine the objects when the second generic type is `Long` as below:

```java
public static <E extends MyGen<?, Long>> long combineValue(Set<E> set) {
    return set.stream()
              .map(MyGen::getValue)
              .reduce(0L, (a,b) -> a | b);
}
```

Now I want to have a similar method when the second type is an `Integer`. So I tried updating the above same method to :

```java
public static <E extends MyGen<?, ? extends Number>> long combineValue(Set<E> set) {
    return (long) set.stream()
                     .map(MyGen::getValue)
                     .reduce((a,b) -> a | b) // error1
                     .orElse(0); // error2

}
```

But the following errors are displayed:

1. error1

> The operator | is undefined for the argument type(s) capture#4-of ?
> extends java.lang.Number, capture#4-of ? extends java.lang.Number

2. error2

> The method orElse(capture#4-of ? extends Number) in the type
> Optional<capture#4-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the
> arguments (int)

Is there any way to handle both `Long` and `Integer` in the same method or could it be done only using two separate methods?

Comment: `.map(MyGen::getValue).mapToLong(Number::longValue)`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat great. you could have added that as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be fine about the return value of this common method being `long`. In that case, it is possible, because you can get a `long` from a `Number` using `longValue`:

```
public static long combineValue(Set<? extends MyGen<?, ? extends Number>> set) {
    return set.stream()
              .map(MyGen::getValue)
              .mapToLong(Number::longValue)
              .reduce(0L, (a,b) -> a | b);
}
```

You basically turn every number into `long`s first, and then do the reduction.

Comment: Could also be mapped with a single `.mapToLong(g -> g.getValue().longValue())`. Or everything at once: `set.stream().reduce(0L, (l, g) -> l | g.getValue().longValue(), (a,b) -> a | b)`